# creating an SQL table using 4 tables

Tags: sql, database

This is what I have thus far however I keep getting an error:

> ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'city' in field list is ambiguous

```
select 
    name as Project_name,
    concat(fName,' ',lName) as Staff_name, 
    city as Branch_city 
from 
    Project a 
join 
    Working b on b.pcode = a.pcode 
join 
    Staff2 c on b.staffNo = c.staffNo 
join 
    Branch d on c.branchNo = d.branchNo 
group by  
    b.pcode, b.staffNo 
having
    count(year) > 1;
```

How do I adjust this so the table output is as shown above. Here are all the tables individually and what they store

Branch table

| branchNo | street | city | postcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B002 | 56 Cover Drive | London | NW10 6EU |
| B003 | 163 Main Street | Glasgow | G11 9QX |
| B004 | 32 Manse Road | Bristol | BS99 1NZ |
| B005 | 22 Deer Road | London | SW1 4EH |
| B007 | 16 Argyll Street | Aberdeen | AB2 3SU |

Staff2 table

| staffNo | fName | lName | position | sex | DOB | salary | branchNo | superno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | New | Engineer | Intern | M | 2000-01-01 | 9000.00 | B002 | SL21 |
| CC1 | Super | User | DBA | M | 1995-01-01 | 90000.00 | B005 | SG14 |
| SA9 | Mary | Howe | Assistant | F | 1970-02-19 | 9000.00 | B007 | SG5 |
| SG14 | David | Ford | Supervisor | M | 1958-03-24 | 18000.00 | B003 | SG5 |
| SG37 | Ann | Beech | Assistant | F | 1960-11-10 | 12000.00 | B003 | SG5 |
| SG5 | Susan | Brand | Manager | F | 1940-06-03 | 24000.00 | B003 | SL21 |
| SL21 | John | White | Manager | M | 1945-10-01 | 30000.00 | B005 | NULL |
| SL41 | Julie | Lee | Assistant | F | 1965-06-13 | 9000.00 | B005 | SL21 |
| XY1 | New | Tester | Assistant | M | 1990-01-01 | 8000.00 | B002 | SL21 |

Project table

| pcode | name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P01 | Kean University | Union |
| P02 | Citi Bank | NYC |
| P03 | British Museum | London |
| P04 | Buckingham Palace | London |
| P05 | Granite | Aberdeen |

Working table

| pcode | staffNo | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P01 | ABC1 | 1980 |
| P01 | ABC1 | 2010 |
| P01 | SG5 | 2000 |
| P02 | XY1 | 2014 |
| P02 | SG5 | 2002 |
| P02 | SG5 | 2018 |
| P02 | SL21 | 2006 |
| P03 | ABC1 | 1995 |
| P03 | SG37 | 1995 |
| P03 | SG14 | 2003 |
| P03 | CC1 | 1990 |
| P03 | CC1 | 2019 |

Identifying error in SQL code and how to get proper out put as indicated

this is the problem question for reference Create a view vHW_#_xxxx to list the project name, staff name and the staff’s branch city for the same staff who working on the same project more than one time. You should use Project, Staff2, Branch, and Working tables in the dreamhome database.. The output column header should be (Project_name, Staff_name, Branch_city). The staff_name should combine fname and lname with a space in between. Below is a sample output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yphad.png)

Comment: this is the problem question for reference Create a view vHW_#_xxxx to list the project name, staff name and the staff’s branch city
for the same staff who working on the same project more than one time. You should use Project, Staff2,
Branch, and Working tables in the dreamhome database.. The output column header should be
(Project_name, Staff_name, Branch_city). The staff_name should combine fname and lname with a space in
between. Below is a sample output:

Comment: Please see [how to format tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support). Also, you did not display an error or your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Error you got is related to this:

```
select name as Project_name,
       concat(fName,' ',lName) as Staff_name,
       city as Branch_city
       ----
        ^
        |
    this "city"
```

because column `city` exists in `branch` and `project` tables; if you don't qualify it with table name (or its alias), database doesn't know which one you meant and doesn't know which one to fetch - therefore, it reports it to be *ambiguous*. According to column alias (`Branch_city`), it looks as if it should've been `d.city` as `branch` table's alias is `d`.

---

However, once you fix that, query won't work because `group by` should contain all non-aggregated columns from the `select` column list. As there's no aggregation at all, it means that ALL columns should be part of `group by`. Though, that wouldn't help much, I think.

Reading comment you posted (it would've been better if you posted it as part of question; also, desired result would also help us help you), this is how I understood it:

```
select 
  a.name as Project_name,
  concat(c.fName, ' ', c.lName) as Staff_name,
  d.city as Branch_city 
from Project a join Working b ON b.pcode    = a.pcode 
               join Staff2 c  ON b.staffNo  = c.staffNo 
               join Branch d  ON c.branchNo = d.branchNo 
where a.staffno in (select w.staffNo
                    from Working w
                    group by w.staffNo, w.pcode
                    having count(*) > 1
                   );
```

Comment: Sample output has been added